# Why does my Python code fail unit testing?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have this challenge:

> Create a function called binary_converter. Inside the function, implement an algorithm to convert decimal numbers between 0 and 255 to their binary equivalents.
>
> For any invalid input, return string Invalid input
>
> Example: For number 5 return string 101

Unit test code is below

```
import unittest


class BinaryConverterTestCases(unittest.TestCase):
  def test_conversion_one(self):
    result = binary_converter(0)
    self.assertEqual(result, '0', msg='Invalid conversion')

  def test_conversion_two(self):
    result = binary_converter(62)
    self.assertEqual(result, '111110', msg='Invalid conversion')

  def test_no_negative_numbers(self):
    result = binary_converter(-1)
    self.assertEqual(result, 'Invalid input', msg='Input below 0 not allowed')

  def test_no_numbers_above_255(self):
    result = binary_converter(300)
    self.assertEqual(result, 'Invalid input', msg='Input above 255 not allowed')
```

my code goes below

```
def binary_converter(n):
   
    if(n==0):
        return "0"
    
    elif(n>255):
        
        return "invalid input"
    elif(n < 0):
        return "invalid input"
    else:
        ans=""
        while(n>0):
            temp=n%2
            ans=str(temp)+ans
            n=n/2
        return ans
```

Unit test results

```
Total Specs: 4 Total Failures: 2

1. test_no_negative_numbers

    `Failure in line 19, in test_no_negative_numbers self.assertEqual(result, 'Invalid input', msg='Input below 0 not allowed') AssertionError: Input below 0 not allowed`

2. test_no_numbers_above_255

    `Failure in line 23, in test_no_numbers_above_255 self.assertEqual(result, 'Invalid input', msg='Input above 255 not allowed') AssertionError: Input above 255 not allowed`
```

Comment: "Invalid" != "invalid" ?

Comment: No worries - you can spend forever staring at things like that without seeing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing strings in Python cares cases.

```
>>> 'invalid input' == 'Invalid input'
False
```

You need to adjust test code or implementation code so that string literals matches exactly.

```
def test_no_negative_numbers(self):
    result = binary_converter(-1)
    self.assertEqual(result, 'Invalid input', msg='Input below 0 not allowed')
                              ^--- (UPPERCASE)

...

elif(n < 0):
    return "invalid input"
            ^--- (lowercase)
```